# How to prevent conditional GET in IIS?

Tags: iis

I have been asked to find a way of preventing IIS from making conditional GETS (So the web server will always return 200 OK or an error if there is one).  Is there a way to do this?

I am using IIS 6 in Windows Sever 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional GET is a part of the [HTTP 1.1 standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).  IIS can't disable it specifically, but it's possible you could write an ISAPI filter that strips out the conditional request headers: If-Modified-Since, If-Unmodified-Since,
   If-Match, If-None-Match, If-Range

I don't know of a readily available package to do this, so you may have to roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

[IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com) is a free URL Rewriter for IIS, that can rewrite the headers, using the RewriteHeader directive.   It would look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE}  ^.+$
RewriteHeader HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE: .*  $1
```

Which basically says, if the "If-Modified-Since" header is non-empty, rewrite it to have *nothing*.  You would have to have similar rules for the other headers.

Check [the doc for IIRF](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/IIRFhelp) online.

Answer (score 0):

This [kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=922733) describes how conditional gets are constructed (or not) in iis 5 and iis 6. You might setup two web servers and force their ETag values to be different, then make sure each request is bounced back and forth between the two servers. That way you should always get a 200 OK response, and the browser will not use the cache.

Apparently this is bad for performance, because it makes it so the web server is always serving the resource even when it doesn't have to.